# Launcher icon cannot be seen

Tags: android, android-studio, icons, android-launcher

Indeed, as you guys may have guessed I am a newbie to android, and the issue I am asking is quite common; however, even when I did everything according to the tutorials and guides. The app icon is not changing. My emulator is API 25, and until now, I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the app, checking the intent fillers in `manifest` folder, and deleting and re-getting the ic_launcher photo. Here, the photos of the some of my files.[image: intent-fillers in my activity tag]

[image: here I have inserted the images]
[image: Here how I saved the photos in my mipmap folder]

Thanks.
By the way, this is how I implemented my picture.
[image]

Comment: Did you create this ic_launcher folder yourself?

Comment: Yes. Actually, for some unknown reason it started working. Thanks for your consideration by the way.